# Circular progress bar is not showing progress for 10% when it show for 60%

Tags: android, xml, progress-bar

I have a circular progress bar and it is working properly when it show 60%. But it does not show any `progress` for 10% result.The `progress` is shown with the help of `adapter`. Can you please help me?

My code is:

```
<ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/progressbar"
     style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:max="100"
     android:indeterminate="false" 
     android:progressBackgroundTint="#D3D3D3"
     android:progress="50"
     android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Comment: share your **`drawable/progressbar`**

Comment: put your code from where you set progree means java code

Comment: I see that android:progress is set to 50 in your code which means 50% is completed.  you can set it to less than 10 to show 10% result.

Comment: if you set progress from java then no worry about xml  @Chithra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1">


      <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/cmll_progrssbar"
           style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
           android:layout_width="70dp"    
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:indeterminate="false"
           android:layoutDirection="rtl"
           android:max="100"
           android:progress="100"
           android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circle_progress_uncomplete" />

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/cmll_completed_per"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
          android:layout_alignLeft="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
          android:layout_alignRight="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
          android:layout_alignTop="@id/cmll_progrssbar"
          android:layout_gravity="center"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:padding="10dp"
          android:text="100%" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Now Create **`@drawable/circle_progress_uncomplete`** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorLightOrange" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270">
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
                android:useLevel="true">
                <solid android:color="@color/colorOrange" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**OUTPUT WITH 10% PROGRESS**

[image]

**OUTPUT WITH 100% PROGRESS**

[image]